# how sanitize the input when set up micro service using mercurius graphql based on fastify

Tags: fastify

I create micro service using mercurius based on fastify, Now i create a plugin to sanitize all the input by hooking onRequest

```html
'use strict'

const fp = require('fastify-plugin')
const mongoSanitize = require('mongo-sanitize');
// the use of fastify-plugin is required to be able
// to export the decorators to the outer scope
console.log('11111')
module.exports = fp(async function (fastify, opts) {
  console.log('222')

  fastify.addHook('onRequest', (request, reply, next) => {
    console.log('333',request)

    // Sanitize request parameters
    request.params = sanitizeObject(request.params);

    // Sanitize query parameters
    request.query = sanitizeObject(request.query);

    // Sanitize request body
    request.body = sanitizeObject(request.body);

    next();
  });
 
})
function sanitizeObject(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null) {
    return obj;
  }

  const sanitizedObj = {};
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if(typeof value === 'string'){
      loggerService.info("Sanitize: " + value);
      sanitizedObj[key] = xss(mongoSanitize(value));
    }else{
      sanitizedObj[key] = sanitizeObject(value);
    }
  }

  return sanitizedObj;
}
```

But i found request.params request.query  request.body all are null
I do not want to use joi to set schema for each input.
I need sanitize all the input using this plugin.
How?

Comment: They are not null, empty at least - please add some code to replicate your issue